# Foreach throw associative array using php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an associative array and want to print a value...in this case i want to create a foreach  to print only [payout] value. 
**Please find below array structure**.

```
Array
(

[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [clicks] => 0
                [conversions] => 0
                [payout] => $0.00
                [erpc] => $0.00
                [cpl] => $0.00
            )
    )
[success] => 1
[totalNumRows] => 1)
```

Comment: `foreach($array['data'] as $entry) echo $entry['payout'];`

Comment: why with `foreach`? Isn't it enough to do just `echo $array['data'][0]['payout']`?

Comment: Because it's in the question, @n-dru. "i want to create a foreach"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through each sub-array like so:

```
  foreach($all_data as $data) {
      echo $data['payout'];
  }
```

If you have more nested arrays, simply `foreach` again for each layer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your array is called $x:

```
if (isset($x['data']) && is_array($x['data']))
{
    foreach ($x['data'] as $dataRow)
        echo $dataRow['payout'] . '<br />';
}
```

should do what you need. It checks if your associative array has data key and if it's an array too. Then it loops through all the records and outputs the payout values.

Comment: Thanks guys i really appreciate your answers.It's works for me.Just can't understand why people downvote my question.anyway

Comment: *Technically* there is nothing wrong with the question, @alb . Most people probably downvoted though, because the solution could've been found with a simple google search.